# TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have written this google app script. 
Purpose: Every time I edit "Location Update" script should send an email to "Broker Email".
[Here is Link to spread sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Lfl06sDNhtbumzjWottLnsBu0b_GB15d2ypH_Dbz_EY/edit?usp=sharing):

```html
function onEdit(e) {
  var activateSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(activateSheet.getSheetByName('Responses'));
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var row = e.range.getRowIndex();//Gets the row the change was made to.  

  var timestamp = sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValues(); //Gets the email
  var load = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValues(); //Gets the email
  var email = sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValues(); //Gets the email
  var location = sheet.getRange(row, 4).getValues(); //Gets the email
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("template");
 template.load = load;
 template.location =location;


  MailApp.sendEmail(email,"Hi","this is my email",{htmlBody: template.evaluate().getContent()});
   }
```

```html
<html>
<h1><b>This is a Check-In call for load number: <?= load ?></b></h1>
<p>
<?= location ?>
</p>
<p>
Please do not reply this email, we don't read these emails. If you have any questions/concers please <a href="google.com">Click Here</a>. We will get back to as soon as we can.
</p>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to this site. What is your question actually?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40288685/typeerror-cannot-read-property-source-from-undefined)

Answer (score 8):

The error:

> Cannot read property “range” from undefined

Means that getting `range`  from event object `e` failed.

If you are running the code from inside the script editor, you will get a range error.  In the case of a simple `onEdit()` trigger, you can only test the code by actually editing a cell.  The `e` event variable will not have anything assigned to it unless you actually edit a cell.  That `e` variable will be assigned an event object when the event (a cell edit) happens.

The function name `onEdit()` is a reserved function name.  In order for the `onEdit()` function to run when a cell is edited, all you need to do is create a function of that name, as opposed to going through a set-up process to assign an event to a function name.  `onEdit()` is a simple trigger.  And "installable" trigger needs to be set-up.

I ran your code, and don't get any range errors, *if* I trigger it by editing a cell.

I am getting an error stating that I don't have permission to send an email.  Which is because the trigger is a "simple" trigger.  You may need to create an installable trigger in order to have permission to send the email.

Answer (score 2):

Try this script (also posted on google docs help forum)

```
function sendMail(e) {

var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
if (sheet.getName() !== 'Responses' || e.range.columnStart !== 6 || e.range.rowStart < 2) return;
var values = e.range.offset(0, -5, 1, 6)
   .getValues()[0];
var htmlBody = '<body>' + 'Hi<br>'
+ '<h1><b>This is a Check-In call for load number:' + values[3] + '</b></h1>'
+ '<p>' + values[5] + '<\p>'
+ '<p>' + 'Please do not reply this email, we don\'t read these emails. If you have any questions/concers please <a href="google.com">Click Here</a>.'
+ 'We will get back to as soon as we can.</p>'
+ '<\body>'
MailApp.sendEmail(values[4], 'subject', "", {
   htmlBody: htmlBody
});
}
```

Set an installable onEdit trigger and see if that works ?