# Setting a value in a drop down with Google Sheets using a script to choose last non-blank cell

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, google-sheets

Edit: Here is an example sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kBeOvXwWZEFoeqPd0ET_e1HLhoGQPvuHK6JFXFRjMOQ/edit?usp=sharing

If I was smarter, I could probably find my solution based off this other user's question who found their own answer.

[Setting a value in a drop down with Google Sheets using a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51199279/setting-a-value-in-a-drop-down-with-google-sheets-using-a-script#new-answer)

I'm trying to do something similar, but here is my situation.

- Cell A1, you choose from a list (drop down)
- Column C data changes based on selection in A1 (uses a filter
  function to pull a list of dates)
- B3 uses Data Validation to change its list based on C3:C

Every time I change A1 (by manually choosing a new option in the drop down), I want B3 to set to the last non blank value in column C, because they are timestamps from a google form, so they should always be in order (most recent date/time should be last value).

If its not too much to ask, if you have a solution, if you could add some comments in your code to explain what is doing what, that would be AWESOME.

For instance, in the above linked other post, I see where he sets row values, but I don't understand why there are no column values.

```
var NEW_ISSUE ='New Issue';
var row;
var default_status;

function defaultValue() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); //I would need to choose a specific sheet, not just an active sheet
 var startRow = 1;
 var numRows = 900;
 var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 4, numRows);
 var data = dataRange.getValues();
 var statusRange = sheet.getRange(startRow,8,numRows);
 var status = statusRange.getValues();

//above I don't understand why not var set for column

 for (var i = 0; data[i] != ''; ++i)
  { 
   if (status[i]  == '')
   {
    sheet.getRange(i+startRow, 8).setValue(NEW_ISSUE);
   }
  }//I can guess this for function looks for the first blank value, and then returns the previous value.
}
```

EDIT:

Thanks to the user below, I am using their suggestion, but altered it to find my specific sheet, and I housed the max value in B2 instead of Z1.

```
function onEdit2(e) {
  var range = e.range
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('CSP Audit Lookup'))
  if (range.getColumn() == 1 && range.getRow() == 1) { // if edit range = A1
    ss.getRange("B3").setValue(ss.getRange("B2").getValue()) // set value of B3 to that of B2, which is index filtered to find max of C
  }
}
```

Edit 8/14 7:54 PM ET

Here is my current script. It works. But, I need it to choose only a specific sheet by name. I've tried 3 different options and they all don't work. I don't get any type of error, they just don't run.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  if (range.getColumn() == 1 && range.getRow() == 1) { // if edit range = A1
    ss.getRange("B3").setValue(ss.getRange("B2").getValue())
    ss.getRange("D3").setValue(ss.getRange("D2").getValue())
    ss.getRange("F3").setValue(ss.getRange("F2").getValue())
    ss.getRange("H3").setValue(ss.getRange("H2").getValue())
    ss.getRange("J3").setValue(ss.getRange("J2").getValue())
    ss.getRange("L3").setValue(ss.getRange("L2").getValue())
    ss.getRange("N3").setValue(ss.getRange("N2").getValue())
    ss.getRange("P3").setValue(ss.getRange("P2").getValue())
    ss.getRange("R3").setValue(ss.getRange("R2").getValue())
    ss.getRange("T3").setValue(ss.getRange("T2").getValue())
    ss.getRange("V3").setValue(ss.getRange("V2").getValue())
    ss.getRange("X3").setValue(ss.getRange("X2").getValue())
    ss.getRange("Z3").setValue(ss.getRange("Z2").getValue())// set value of B3 to that of Z1, which is max of C
  }
}
```

**My Final Solution! Thank You HaPhan!** HaPHan also recommended I use copyValuesToRange() instead of all the various ss.getRange(), but CopyValuestoRange() didn't seem to work for me, but its fast enough. Thanks again!

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var specificSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CSP Audit Lookup")
  if (range.getColumn() == 1 && range.getRow() == 1) { // if edit range = A1
    ss.getRange("B3").setValue(ss.getRange("B2").getValue())
    ss.getRange("D3").setValue(ss.getRange("D2").getValue())
    ss.getRange("F3").setValue(ss.getRange("F2").getValue())
    ss.getRange("H3").setValue(ss.getRange("H2").getValue())
    ss.getRange("J3").setValue(ss.getRange("J2").getValue())
    ss.getRange("L3").setValue(ss.getRange("L2").getValue())
    ss.getRange("N3").setValue(ss.getRange("N2").getValue())
    ss.getRange("P3").setValue(ss.getRange("P2").getValue())
    ss.getRange("R3").setValue(ss.getRange("R2").getValue())
    ss.getRange("T3").setValue(ss.getRange("T2").getValue())
    ss.getRange("V3").setValue(ss.getRange("V2").getValue())
    ss.getRange("X3").setValue(ss.getRange("X2").getValue())
    ss.getRange("Z3").setValue(ss.getRange("Z2").getValue())// set value of B3 to that of Z1, which is max of C
  }
}
```

Comment: if you look [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) you will see there is a .getRange function with 3 parameters, which return a column of data started from the top left cell at given coordinate.

So in your above code, his `data` will consist data from range D1:D900 and his `status` will consist data from range H1:H900.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in short you just want to set B3 to the maximum date populated by column C each time you change A1

My approach for this matter might be a little sloppy.

First use another cell to get the max value of column C. Here I assume you use cell Z1, `=MAX(C3:C)`.

Then set that value into cell B3 whenever A1 change. I use `onEdit(e)` for this purpose.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  if (range.getColumn() == 1 && range.getRow() == 1) { // if edit range = A1
    ss.getRange("B3").setValue(ss.getRange("Z1").getValue()) // set value of B3 to that of Z1, which is max of C
  }
}
```

If you set the `=MAX()` directly into B3, it will break the data validation of B3. Therefore I use Z1 as a medium for the correct data.

Comment: This is so simple and lovely. My only issue is that Column C is all Plain Text Only. This was the only way I could get some other formulas to work (google sheets really hates Date TIme entries from Forms)

Comment: in place of =MAX(C3:C) I am using =index(C:C,max(filter(row(C:C),len(C:C)))) which I found from https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/b72YKIXXyes
I am about to text the script you created now.

Comment: I am getting an error: TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 2, file "ResetAuditLookup"). I read that this is normal when trying to run from the script editor. How do I make the script run? I edit Cell A1, but the script doesn't seem to run.

Comment: Message 'Error: Cannot read property "range" from undefined' is generated because the variable "range" is not declared in that function. I think you missed the `var range` declaration.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, as research told me thats a pretty normal error. Is the above code missing semi-colons? Because There aren't any in the example.

Comment: You probably want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911101/typeerror-cannot-read-property-range-from-undefined), which stated out that if you try to debug onEdit function from the script editor, the `e` event variable will not have anything assigned to it unless you actually edit a cell.

Comment: The code I wrote up there runs smoothly when I edit my A1 cell

Comment: This is what my code looks like now. I have multiple sheets on my spreadsheet, so maybe I broke something by trying to select a specific sheet? Code looks messy in comments, so I'll edit my post.

Comment: Am I suppose to be dropping this function into the sheet somewhere?

Comment: I had to delete the script and re-add it, and it works. Except I need it to only run on a specific sheet. Every method I've tried using to choose the specific sheet seems to break the script.

Comment: You will have to assign that sheet to a variable, like so : `var specificSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CSP Audit Lookup")` and set value into that sheet.
Also, using that much of `getValue()` and `setValue()` will take a lot of execute time, you can use `copyValueToRange()` instead : `ss.getRange("B3:Z3").copyValuesToRange(specificSheet,2,26, 2,2)`